# How to remove Fractional value from timestamp MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

> Fractional value from timestamp MySQL

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `note` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL',
  `note` text,
  `updated` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
```

Query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated) WHERE id = 1;
```

Result:
1491556345.0002231 Somthing

But I want just  1491556345 , How to remove Fractional value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) for this:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated),0) WHERE id = 1;
```